# Convert a vectoral PDF to myscript compatible svg

Tags: pdf, svg

I was taking handwriting notes so often, but cannot search in it. I met with myscript studio and my life got easier. Ftware. But, the problems begun when I want to take notes with iPhone instead of a digital pen. Luckily, iPhone apps (Neu.Notes+, FastFinga, HandyNotes etc..) export these handwritten notes as PDF that contains vectoral data.

I googled but nothing could find any useful tool to convert these type of PDF files to myscript compatible svg or other files in order to search in handwritten text ability. Then, I decided writing little python script based on Graham I Cummins's that is converting the vectoral PDF to svg. Is therea better solution?

My script is available from https://rapidshare.com/files/1754666267/Pdf2Svg.rar

Comment: Just a note, apparently the link is broken.

Comment: I tried inkscape and pdf2svg to convert vector pdfs from my Boogie Board Sync and neither was able to create an svg that MyScript would open. For reference, pdf2svg is [here](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) and inkscape is [here](http://www.inkscape.org/). Wikipedia has a nice [tutorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Graphic_Lab/Resources/PDF_conversion_to_SVG#Conversion_with_Inkscape) but, alas, no luck.